Jenkins curl JSON payload issue when deploying to Render API
I am trying to deploy a service to the Render platform using a Jenkins pipeline. The deployment requires making a POST request with a JSON payload to the Render API.
However, I keep running into errors when sending the JSON payload. I suspect it may be related to how the payload is formatted or passed in the curl command.
Here is my Jenkins pipeline stage:
`
stage('Deploy to Render') {
steps {
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'render-credentials', variable: 'RENDER_API_KEY')]) {
script {
def payload = """
{
"serviceId": "${SERVICE_ID}",
"clearCache": true
}
""".trim()
            sh """
            curl -v -X POST \
                -H "Authorization: Bearer \$RENDER_API_KEY" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -d '${payload}' \
                https://api.render.com/v1/services/${SERVICE_ID}/deploys
            """
        }
    }
}

}
`
Here’s the error i got:
error
Is my approach to building the JSON payload with triple quotes and passing it using -d correct?

Too many quotes can lead to errors just write payload content into a file then pass the file to curl, before check manually if the same payload sended from your pc return the same error maybe is a server side issue.
